# POST request from Excel vba on ssl enabled url

Tags: vba, excel, ssl

I'm really tangled over here.
I'm trying to make a authentication login call from my Excel, please find my code below.

```
Sub Authen()
Dim qTestServ As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP 

With qTestServ
    .Open "Post", "https://testURL.com/oauth/token", False
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic encodedvalue="
    .Send ("grant_type=value&username=userOne&password=testing123")
    msgbox(.ResponseText)

    If Not .Status = 200 Then
        MsgBox "UnAuthorized"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End With

Set qTestServ = Nothing
End sub
```

Please find the references added to my projects below.
[image]

Please find error message i'm receiving below.

[image]

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Look again at the source for that page. It probably has a **token** as a hidden `<input>` or teh token is passed along with a cookie. If the former, you need to include that in your string; if the latter then you need to make a previous call and parse the token out of the cookie string. Use JS Fiddle to examine exactly what is going back and forth.

Comment: @Jeeped , there is a API token given by the appication, but where will i pass that?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6d6caec-127f-4a39-9b2e-17f850d2c195/msxml6dll-the-download-of-the-specified-resource-has-failed?forum=xmlandnetfx

Comment: The url provided is a dummy url as it is an internal tool, 

I have the same code structured in "postman" and to make it work i need to Switch Off "SSL Certification verification".

Comment: re: '*where will i pass that*'  - What are the results from your JS Fiddle examination of the posting process?

Comment: @SiddharthRout - you probably know this but the xml object has to be `MSXML2.XMLHTTP60` to use XML v6.0.

Comment: It worked guys it worked... as @TimWilliams suggested url says i was using (Dim qTestServ As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP) to declare and i changed that to (Dim qTestServ As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP).

Comment: @TimWilliams: IMHO you should put that as an answer so that it can help future visitors :D The comments are not permanent  EDIT: Too Late now I guess :D

Comment: @Jeeped: Honestly... No I didn't

Comment: Already done @TimWilliams :) , thanks a ton guys for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion Tim Williams.

I was using `Dim qTestServ As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP` to declare and changed that to `Dim qTestServ As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`

Please find the code below

```
Dim qTestServ As New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP

Sub Authen()
Dim qTestServ As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP 

With qTestServ
    .Open "Post", "https://testURL.com/oauth/token", False
    .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic encodedvalue="
    .Send ("grant_type=value&username=userOne&password=testing123")
    msgbox(.ResponseText)

    If Not .Status = 200 Then
        MsgBox "UnAuthorized"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End With

Set qTestServ = Nothing
End sub
```

Please refer to [msxml6.dll: The download of the specified resource has failed.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6d6caec-127f-4a39-9b2e-17f850d2c195/msxml6dll-the-download-of-the-specified-resource-has-failed?forum=xmlandnetfx)